# Unity Remote Config unstable issue, return curl error 28: Connection timed out after 10005 milliseconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found out that the unity remote config was unstable where sometime the remote config will stop working and return "curl error 28: Connection timed out after 10005 milliseconds" (as attached image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsruS.png)). Where some other time it was working just fine.

What I am trying to do is try to fetch remote config's data, in my case I check the "isMaintenance" bool every 5 second and if it return true, the game will block/sign out the player from playing the game.

I am not sure is the unity remote config will get affect by the connection type (wifi connection or mobile data), as me and my team tested that every time we used mobile data will not have the above issue, while using wifi will caused the error. Did anyone know what is the reason behind the issue?

What we found even strange is that some of the pc does not have this issue while the others will see this inside unity editor while we are all using the same project with the same version of Unity and Remote Config.

We had also make android build to test out too, and wifi connection will always have the error while mobile data connection seems fine and able to retrieve the data from remote config successfully when we called ConfigManager.FetchConfigs() every few seconds.

We added "if (configResponse.status == ConfigRequestStatus.Success)" to checkup the state too, when the error occurs, it always return false in this checking.

We am using Remote Config Version 1.4.0, in Unity 2020.3.19f1

Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed solved it by upgrading the unity remote config version from 1.4.0 to 2.1.2. To anyone come across the same issue, refer to the link below for more detail.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/remote-config-unstable-return-curl-error-28-connection-timed-out-after-10005-milliseconds.1320753/#post-8352144

Answer (score 0):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igrer.png)

disabling the automatically initialize unity gaming services in IAP button catalog works for me.